# Gyroscope.IsSupported always returning false in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, xna-4.0

I am tryin to test the gyroscope function for my windows phone app hoever I can't get the gyroscope to return a value when testing with the simulator. I am using Microsoft.Devices.Sensors and I have added it as a reference. I have tried rebuilding, opening and closing visual studio, cleaning the solution and restarting the simulator but it makes no difference.

Is there something I have to do to enable the gyroscope on my simulator?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gyroscope is not available on the Window Phone 7.5 emulator. The only link I found saying that was at the bottom of a post by [Jeff Blankenburg](http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2011/11/05/31-days-of-mango-day-5-gyroscope/). Instead use a real device?

Comment: Thanks, we were able to use the accelerometer instead :)